# Encrypt /boot partition after installation

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, encryption, luks

I have a fresh installation of Kubuntu 20.10.
In the installer, I chose the option for full-disk encryption. The partition holding my system (the one mounted at `/`) is now encrypted.

But `/boot` is still un-encrypted. This exposes me to [evil maid attacks](https://github.com/nyxxxie/de-LUKS).

The most updated how-to guide for full disk encryption in Ubuntu (including `/boot`) [I have found](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019) dates back to 2019, would have me to reinstall everything from scratch.

I already have the system partition encrypted, now I only need to encrypt /boot.

Is there a way to encrypt the `/boot` partition without having to reinstall everything?

Comment: Never encrypted a `/boot` partition before, but this looks pretty promising without wiping out your installation:  https://cryptsetup-team.pages.debian.net/cryptsetup/encrypted-boot.html